# Company custom fields's value not saving in company admin form(Magento b2b)

Tags: magento, magento2

I have created some custom fields in company table. After creating the fields in company form, i have used one event to save the custom value in database. So, first time the value is saving in database but it is not saving in UI component form rather it is showing as a blank.

1. customer_form.xml

```
<fieldset name="proofofbusiness" sortOrder="100">
    <settings>
        <collapsible>true</collapsible>
        <label> Proof of Business </label>
    </settings>
    <field name="gst_number" formElement="input">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">gst_number</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">GST Number</label>
            <dataType>text</dataType>
            <dataScope>gst_number</dataScope>
        </settings>
    </field>
</fieldset>
```

2)di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Company\Model\Company\DataProvider" type="Arijit\CustomerShop\Model\CustomerShop\DataProvider" />
    <type name="Magento\Company\Model\Company\DataProvider">
    <plugin name="after_save_company_additional_field"
            type="Arijit\CustomerShop\Plugin\AdditionalDataProvider"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

3)db_schema.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="company" resource="default" engine="innodb">
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="gst_number" nullable="true"/>
</table>
</schema>
```

4. Dataprovider.php(Added custom field)

   public function getProofOfBusiness(CompanyInterface $company)
   {
   return [
   'gst_number'=> $company->getGstNumber(),
   ];
   }

Answer (score 0):

I can see that the fieldset name is not matching the function name that returns its data. The fieldset name is "proofofbusiness" so your function in DataProvider.php should be named getProofofbusinessData().